# "Turning on FM Radio" Why?

Tags: android, radio

I have a HTC wildfire S that has an FM tuner. In order for me to use the FM radio I need to have a headset plugged in. My question is why does it take time (there is a progress bar) to "turn on the FM". Isn't it just a tuner? How come other very basic FM radios "turn on" instantly?

Comment: which stackoverflow forum would this be applicable in?

Comment: It's the Stack Exchange network, but I don't know if the Android.SE site would be applicable or not. It is definitely off topic for Super User though

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Fm tuner per the manual see link: [htc-wildfire-s-tmobile-ug](http://dl3.htc.com/htc_na/user_guides/htc-wildfire-s-tmobile-ug.pdf) but a app meaning it is accessing the FM station(s) via the network.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, just like on my Huawei U8180 with Cyanogen mod, the app needs to enable bluetooh support for FM radio capabilities.

EDIT: check [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/30468) for details on why it needs BT support.

> Depending on handset, Silicon Industries is one, si470x (x being 8 or
>   9) is common (used on Galaxy 5, Zte Blade), there's Texas Instruments
>   (TI) which shares the bluetooth functionality within the TI chip-set -
>   we're talking SoC (System on Chip), by sending a series of bluetooth
>   HCI commands, the FM radio receiver starts up.

Comment: Why would the FM radio require bluetooth? Aren't they different technologies with different purposes?

Comment: answer edited to answer your comment